# Range based for loop index

Tags: c++, iterator, compiler-optimization

A custom iterator on a std::vector returns an object of the following class:

```
class chunk {
public:
    int    value_;
    size_t fake_index_;
};
```

The iterator updates both the `fake_index_` and `value_`.

After that I create a range class with the iterator. Then in a range base for loop over the range class, I only use the `value_`, but not `fake_index_`.

Does that means the compiler will optimize out the iterator's update of `fake_index_` ?

Test Code (with all the iterator stuff...)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class Iterator;

class Chunk {

public:
    int value_;
    int base_bit_index_;
    int real_index_;
    std::vector<int>& data_;
    Chunk (std::vector<int>& data, size_t real_index)
            : data_{data}
    {
        base_bit_index_ = real_index*sizeof(int);
        real_index_ = real_index;
        value_ = data[real_index_];
    }
    int value() { return value_; }
private:
    void increment_index() {
        ++real_index_;
        base_bit_index_ += sizeof(int);
        value_ = data_[real_index_];
    }
    friend class Iterator;
};

class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
private:
    Chunk chunk_;
public:
    Iterator(Chunk chunk) :chunk_(chunk) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator& mit) : chunk_(mit.chunk_) {}
    Iterator& operator++() {
        chunk_.increment_index();
        return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator++(int) {Iterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs)
    {
        return chunk_.real_index_== rhs.chunk_.real_index_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs)
    {
        return !(operator==(rhs));
    }
    Chunk& operator*() {return chunk_;}
};
class Range
{
private:
    std::vector<int>& data_;
public:
    Range(std::vector<int>& data)
        : data_{data}
    {
    }
    Iterator begin()
    {
        Chunk chunk(data_, 0);
        Iterator tmp(chunk);
        return tmp;
    }
    Iterator end()
    {
        Chunk chunk(data_, data_.size());
        Iterator tmp(chunk);
        return tmp;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.resize(100);
    std::vector<int> v2;
    Range X(v1);
    for (auto chunk : X) {
        v2.push_back(chunk.real_index_);
    }
}
```

[gcc godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYFsAOBLANgUwCcAabECNLPIkYANgCZiAzPAFyIGdyAjEAcgAM/YpXT4AdmwDyE3AE8Bw4gBNshfMjbYAbvm5CR2KflxL%2BASmKpM21BIMBaacwCGnNpeJn%2BAVhES5tYCAKQMAMwAjADUAO7YbAjRAB4AHHSOdAAs0cDIyNF0AHQMImzmFlYA1iC%2Bgt4CWQFBqAIi3PXlhlZwsEhoKvgAompsqCRkEABWIJHWttj23BSouKgAroTYnPgAgpzoQZQ4BLIAwgiuEsD4FcScG4TIt/xh4cbIuOuD0SHhZ3otOM/kMQoJdm8Pl8fn8zgkiK4xoQQWCIREod98L9/osPBpXOgUeDPu5ONEAJIcQiI4HhABCqNRJM4ZIu6wkVV%2BAHYGeDUZh1jxcNhkCBUdEJdFjGxojpXF98AB9P683aSqVSaI8dxKngJRXGQbJZX08WS6XRfG4A0SI0m1XqjwqEAgQFI2HSlEMOjRFSI1z2s0Stkc6IQJ0ut20uFSL0%2Bv1sVzEaKcbAALyVMqtNqNFiD6oLIF9/uVPITrhCXIAIvnKw6CxLtTtFXq2Dn8MbsVXLfh5e3kgAqVMZ1DMCDSvOm8ENiXZw0dxVdnt9%2BfJFX59VyhWLv7d8shXx0ue2hcHmtTtWSys16fmzVb9b4CAWbl0ntsTYSWXyx/27k33ZMC2OUODFW8JR0VBsBUDVkA0cQpH7Z9Xw3K8GAZdDjztddwILJtdX1Vcd3Q3cU3TfBR3HKRJ3rBsHyVJdy2VQ8sNPXxz1o/982YLZJBg5kyUpBF3Qva8cIhYlcFJCkqRpQhoiLAUhRFFM2GdEB4WpESzgjDSJAFNtNLkxVE2AZNPXCUE%2BR5flgMRW58xDTlkAQdkqkDcElOFUV8yErTxggJzohctyXxQVyOUVCgIqqF86zE3C/LklYHBlJL3W9aJ0ASMLgpiqLsrYIoQsiuKbOrXzZIyn0bGE4ESPQ5D4tw9USvcooPngyRDJPZJn3Emd30/aIB0SbYBqvCrEqq8Zolq/zkQaukqLYMq6XS2a2CwCBRoQbYaLmzA6sWjDloOjQP0IL8tswdcpsvRtUFWQ7jt3XcUo8GTXsywgEE4PNcOah6Cwu4a2sVIpWONN7wm7X7OGK/LId7a0iImiUEuBngntwF6FrAMB3rQVKvoWsIfXhgHgaBwbQau6ICYgea5JhqsIEpmja3u9UnPJvG5IHJqeTpr9wbugCxIvATogAJSuG5GRszy7NA/NdKjZEcVjSy%2BaY8SvJFMDgbl64n3VzRtIs0FMvLKnBqLPWy39TH1RpyaAPVDb5J4fBgGMfrAaV4GeZivK3IgJjk0ETmWslL3ohu6LQvRkH8Eu66sBTl245m%2BS%2BID6mg8GoK2ojktkyYophyfSoU893OE%2B2tqY%2BDyURcb26L1d%2B7JdVC10Fcf2qbdiVzaBTWYzYEFZUiFOdEiZHq4gSJBGjlOx8t7WhllBgU5Nm5ogADQgeeW/VZhZogVx1jGMPQyLQ%2B1tQiCGCKAVOAQFtXGQKok45ZGVy9UVGfd2isqxeB8P4YggR%2BCRBEK0fgZwwinRTI8Z4vwIhwOIF0YQlRiA1DqA0fgTRoEtDaPcEAnQKhWB8KUUhhhgj8DKNQ4gehCCpnsCALIQA)

Test Code (without all the iterator stuff)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        v2.push_back(i);
        // std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    }
}
```

[gcc godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-Ofast'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+v2%3B%0A++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+100%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++v2.push_back(i)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

My first impression: Looks like the iterator sucks horribly anyway.

Comment: There's no way to know with just the code provided. Can we see what the update code looks like?

Comment: Something like `chunk_.fake_index_ += 8*sizeof(int);` for every `++` operation of the iterator.

Comment: if there is no answer, i guess i will just go ahead and write the test code. check it in gcc god bolt, and then see if I should write the actual code.